# How to modify a dynamically-created unordered list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to filter an unordered list using jQuery. The problem is, the list itself (#jqueryFileTree) is loaded dynamically, so I am having trouble manipulating it. The code is below (from http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/):

```
(function ($) {
    // custom css expression for a case-insensitive contains()
    jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    function listFilter(header, list) { // header is any element, list is an unordered list
        // create and add the filter form to the header
        var form = $("<form>").attr({
            "class": "filterform",
            "action": "#"
        }),
            input = $("<input>").attr({
                "class": "filterinput",
                "type": "text"
            });
        $(form).append(input).appendTo(header);

        $(input)
            .change(function () {
                var filter = $(this).val();
                if (filter) {
                    alert($(list).html());
                    // this finds all links in a list that contain the input,
                    // and hide the ones not containing the input while showing the ones that do
                    $(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
                    $(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
                } else {
                    $(list).find("li").slideDown();
                }
                return false;
            })
            .keyup(function () {
                // fire the above change event after every letter
                $(this).change();
            });
    }

    //ondomready
    $(function () {
        listFilter($("#sortable_list_head"), $("#jqueryFileTree"));
    });

}(jQuery));
```

As I understand it, I would need to use the .on() method to listen for an event on the parent of the ul #jqueryFileTree. The thing is, I don't want to listen for any events on the list. All I need to do is listen for an event on the search box, which triggers the find method on the list to filter it. But since the list does not exist when the document is created, find doesn't work.

So, how can I use .find without directly using a listener on a dynamically created element?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also, and faster, call the `listFilter()` function once you have dynamicly inserted your list. `function insertList(...){/*insert the list*/ listFilter($("#sortable_list_head"), $("#myList"));}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the selector instead of the jquery object (*which is empty at the time you call it*)

```
listFilter($("#sortable_list_head"), "#jqueryFileTree");
```

Since you do not cache it, but always do `$(list)` you will have no problem..

Although you could still cache it inside the `change` function

```
.change(function () {
    var filter = this.value,
        $list = $(list);

    if (filter) {
        alert($list.html());
        // this finds all links in a list that contain the input,
        // and hide the ones not containing the input while showing the ones that do
        $list.find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
        $list.find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
    } else {
        $list.find("li").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
})
```

Comment: That was painfully simple. Thanks so much, works beautifully now!